# Switching views in UISegmentedControl in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I am stuck up with a problem to switch views for `UISegmentedControl`. I have imported a framework of `HMSegmentedControl` to use multiple views (7 views). I want to switch views when tapping on New Matches it should display matches view, and when tapping on the Daily Recommendations, it should display matches view and so on. Below is my code. I have tried a lot in switching view by `segmentedControlChangedValue`, but it doesn't work for me. Anything to do or am I doing wrong?

```
  @interface MatchesViewController ()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollVw;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *matchesView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *dailyRecommendationsView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *preferedMatchesView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *broaderMatchesView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *twowayMatcheVsiew;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *reverseMatchesView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *decideLaterView;
  - (IBAction)btnMenuClicked:(id)sender;
  @end

  @implementation MatchesViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.title = @"Matches";
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:16/255.0 green:97/255.0 blue:61/255.0 alpha:1.0];

  [self.navigationController.navigationBar
  setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];


  [self.scrollVw addSubview:self.matchesView];
  [self.scrollVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.matchesView.frame.size.height)];

  [self.scrollVw addSubview:self.dailyRecommendationsView];
  [self.scrollVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.dailyRecommendationsView.frame.size.height)];

  [self.scrollVw addSubview:self.preferedMatchesView];
  [self.scrollVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.preferedMatchesView.frame.size.height)];

  [self.scrollVw addSubview:self.broaderMatchesView];
  [self.scrollVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.broaderMatchesView.frame.size.height)];

  [self.scrollVw addSubview:self.twowayMatcheVsiew];
  [self.scrollVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.twowayMatcheVsiew.frame.size.height)];

  [self.scrollVw addSubview:self.reverseMatchesView];
  [self.scrollVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.reverseMatchesView.frame.size.height)];

  [self.scrollVw addSubview:self.decideLaterView];
  [self.scrollVw setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.decideLaterView.frame.size.height)];

  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;


  CGFloat viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl1 = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"New Matches", @"Daily Recommendations", @"Prefered Matches", @"Broader Matches", @"2-Way Matches", @"Reverse Matches", @"Decide Later"]];
  segmentedControl1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  segmentedControl1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 45);
  segmentedControl1.segmentEdgeInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);
  segmentedControl1.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleFullWidthStripe;
  segmentedControl1.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationDown;


  segmentedControl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:167/255.0 green:148/255.0 blue:4/255.0 alpha:1.0];

  //segmentedControl1.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleBox;
  //segmentedControl1.selectedSegmentIndex = HMSegmentedControlNoSegment;


  segmentedControl1.selectionIndicatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  segmentedControl1.selectionIndicatorHeight = 2.0f;
  segmentedControl1.verticalDividerEnabled = YES;
  segmentedControl1.verticalDividerColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  segmentedControl1.verticalDividerWidth = 1.0f;
  [segmentedControl1 setTitleFormatter:^NSAttributedString *(HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl, NSString *title, NSUInteger index, BOOL selected) {
  NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
  return attString;
  }];

  [segmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl1];

  [self.navigationController.navigationBar
  setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

  }


  - (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
  {

  switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
  case 0:
  self.matchesView.hidden = NO;
  self.dailyRecommendationsView.hidden = YES;
  self.preferedMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.broaderMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.twowayMatcheVsiew.hidden = YES;
  self.reverseMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.decideLaterView.hidden = YES;
  break;
  case 1:
  self.matchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.dailyRecommendationsView.hidden = NO;
  self.preferedMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.broaderMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.twowayMatcheVsiew.hidden = YES;
  self.reverseMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.decideLaterView.hidden = YES;
  break;
  case 2:
  self.matchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.dailyRecommendationsView.hidden = YES;
  self.preferedMatchesView.hidden = NO;
  self.broaderMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.twowayMatcheVsiew.hidden = YES;
  self.reverseMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.decideLaterView.hidden = YES;
  break;
  case 3:
  self.matchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.dailyRecommendationsView.hidden = YES;
  self.preferedMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.broaderMatchesView.hidden = NO;
  self.twowayMatcheVsiew.hidden = YES;
  self.reverseMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.decideLaterView.hidden = YES;
  break;
  case 4:
  self.matchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.dailyRecommendationsView.hidden = YES;
  self.preferedMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.broaderMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.twowayMatcheVsiew.hidden = NO;
  self.reverseMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.decideLaterView.hidden = YES;
  break;
  case 5:
  self.matchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.dailyRecommendationsView.hidden = YES;
  self.preferedMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.broaderMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.twowayMatcheVsiew.hidden = YES;
  self.reverseMatchesView.hidden = NO;
  self.decideLaterView.hidden = YES;
  break;
  case 6:
  self.matchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.dailyRecommendationsView.hidden = YES;
  self.preferedMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.broaderMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.twowayMatcheVsiew.hidden = YES;
  self.reverseMatchesView.hidden = YES;
  self.decideLaterView.hidden = NO;
  break;
  default:
  break;
  }

  }

  - (void)uisegmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {
  NSLog(@"Selected index %ld", (long)segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your method `segmentedControlChangedValue` gets called ?

Try to add a breakpoint on it and to track segment.selectedSegmentIndex value. I think the problem comes from there.

As HMSegmentedControl is not a subclass of UISegmentedControl but of UIControl, the method should be :

```
  - (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(HMSegmentedControl *)segment
```

instead of :

```
  - (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
[segmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The event is not correct.
Try to do following code

```
[segmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Reinstalling your app.